# Mapping from a point inside a disk to a point inside an annulus

Tags: conformal-geometry

How do I map any point inside a disk to a point inside an annulus ?
Disk and annulus are concentric (at the origin).
After some more deep thoughts: may be the origin should not be included in the transformation.